# how to use common modulus attack?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am struck with the following problem:

> Let Alice, Bob, Chris and Eve communicate over a public network. They encrypt all messages they send using RSA system. Bob and Chris have the RSA modulus $n_B$ and $n_C$ respectively with $n_B$ = $n_C$ But different public encryption exponents: $e_B \neq e_C$. Suppose $\gcd(e_B, e_C)=1$, and that Alice sends the same secret message to Bob and Chris.
>
> Show how Eve can decipher the message.

Comment: The question assumes that Alice, Bob and Chris are using raw/textbook RSA, rather than RSA with random padding or hybrid encryption, as they should; therefore, Eve can verify a guess of a message sent by Alice to Bob, e.g. tell if it is head or tail; this fails modern security definition. Independently: Chris can factor his modulus, and since that the same as Bob's, Chris can find Bob's private key (or an equivalent), and decipher messages intended to Bob only, another disaster.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Think about this: what does it mean that $\gcd(e_B, e_C)=1$. Formally that means there exist some $s_1, s_2$ such that $e_Bs_1 + e_Cs_2=1$.

Say you have two ciphertexts (the following math is all done modulo the shared modulus), $C_B=M^{e_B}$ and $C_C=M^{e_C}$. You can do the following:

$$\begin{align}
C_B^{s_1}*C_C^{s_2}&=(M^{e_B})^{s_1}*(M^{e_C})^{s_2}\\
&=M^{e_Bs_1}*M^{e_Cs_2}\\
&=M^{e_Bs_1+e_Cs_2}\\
&=M^1\\
&=M
\end{align}$$

Comment: @mikeazo thanks..this helps to solve my problem..and this is not homework kind of question..i found this problem in an examination paper & i was just curious about it.

Comment: @ShankhaJana Since you found it on an examination paper, you should specify that in the question and give credit to the source.

Comment: @mikeazo how did you move to the 2nd step where  M^e^s1 became M^e*s1

Comment: @Sara, that is just algebra. Maybe I should have put parenthesis to make it more clear what was going on . I'll update.

Comment: Oh right, so this means the message from both parties is multiplied by s1 and s2 respectively right?

Comment: @Sara The ciphertext is raised to the $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively, which multiplies in the exponent.

Comment: A similar problem that may attract your attention, is [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6361/104793).

Comment: should 1+2=1 be mod with N or phi(N)?