# Shared modulus attack on RSA

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, attack, ciphertext-only-attack

Consider a scenario in which a group of people use a common modulus $n$ in the textbook RSA crypto system,
where $n=pq$, $p$ and $q$ are large distinct prime numbers.

Is there any chance for an attacker outside the group to view the original message?

Let me explain my solution. Assume the group members receive the same message. So $c_1= m^{e_1} \bmod n$ and $c_2= m^{e_2} \bmod n$. Assume $e_1$ and $e_2$ are co-prime. So if we can find $x, y$ satisfying $e_1x+ e_2y=1$ then an attacker can view the original message. Am I correct?

Comment: Do you want any specific format for an answer to your homework dump?

Comment: This is not a homework. I'm studying  RSA now. So thinking about different situations. OK. Let me explain my solution. Assume group members receive the same messages. So, c1= m^e1 mod n  and c2= m^e2 mod n. Assume e1 and e2 are co-primes. so if we can find x, y s.t e1x+ e2y=1 then attacker can view the original message. Am I correct?

Comment: Did you search in the site before asking? What about this one?http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack

Comment: Are those people using the same $e$? If no, why?

Comment: Why are you using several exponents? What advantage over a single $e$ do you expect from that?

Comment: In a group of people, different people have different encryption key. That is common. Only the "n" is shared among group members. get it?

Comment: @Mr.Vendetta But what's the point of giving them different keys? Since each of them knows the factors of n, each of them can decrypt messages to any $e$.

Comment: Yes. But in this scenario we trust group members and we want unique encryption keys for each person in the group.

Comment: I'm just trying to picture this using real world numbers.  What you have here is RSA.  Now the public key consists of a public exponent e which is prime and the modulus N.  .NET typically uses an e of 65537.  So you are asking whether, if someone (an attacker, an authorized user) encrypts using an e of 3 or 19 or whatever (which would have a different inverse mod N and therefore a different decryption key) would this break RSA?  No, it wouldn't.  All the information to do this is already available to an attacker (by subbing a new prime for 65537) but it reveals nothing about the original pk.

Comment: ax + by = 1 form is the general shape used to calculate gcd and modular inverse.  It will not help you find the private exponents.

Comment: @WDS, it will if you follow [Lecter's link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29415/shared-modulus-attack-on-rsa#comment67935_29415). And there's also stated why it is a really bad idea to share moduli.

Comment: @SEJPM I feel silly.  I missed the part about the same message being encrypted with the different keys and was thinking in terms of "different messages with different keys."  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @WDS: in RSA, the public exponent $e$ needs not be prime, and is not allways. The public exponent $e$ needs to be coprime with $\varphi(N)$, which is the case if $e$ is a small odd prime, and pulling a factor of $N$ is hard.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a RSA key pair, it means that you know the private key (otherwise this is not "your" key pair). The private key format, normally, contains the two factors $p$ and $q$ (at least so it goes with [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)). Even if all you have are the modulus $n$, the public exponent $e$ and the private exponent $d$, the factorization of $n$ can still be worked out from $e$ and $d$ (see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/14713/28) for a detailed description). The bottom-line is that if two people "share the same modulus" then they also both know the private keys of each other. In effect, there is only one actual key pair and they both know it.

The "shared modulus" situation is thus mostly irrelevant.

---

A second, most important point is that what you described ($c = m^e \pmod n$) is not RSA. It is often, confusingly, called "textbook RSA"; in the same way, a car engine, resting on the floor, could be called a "textbook Ferrari". RSA, as an asymmetric encryption algorithm, is a combination of several operations; the modular exponentiation is the most CPU-intensive of them, but not the only one, and the other operations are very important for security. In the case of PKCS#1, what enters the exponentiation is the *padded message*; the padding includes random bytes.

Even if you imagine a setup where the same message $m$ will be encrypted twice, once with $(n,e)$ and once with $(n,e')$ (same modulus, but distinct exponents), what will be really exponentiated will be, in the first case, a padded value $x$ that includes $m$ and some randomness, and, in the second case, *another* padded value $x'$ that includes $m$ and some other, distinct randomness. This would avoid the reconstruction of $m$ by an attacker observing both encrypted messages.