# Same message space for different public exponents

Tags: rsa

What is the weakness, if there is any, of using the same message space for different public exponents (assuming e changes everytime)?

Imagine I have a message space [0,n] where n is a 1024 bit number and several public exponents of 1024 bit each as well, does that somehow have an impact on my RSA system?

Edit: assume I don't have access to n in this scenario (unless "message space" refers to n. However, in this case we assume that the given message space is a composite number with > 6 prime factors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use common modulus attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack)

Comment: What do you mean: assume I don't have access to $n$ in this scenario? $n$ is part of each and every public key, so in the end everybody with a public exponent should also have $n$. Without clarification on this I would still consider the question a dupe...

Comment: This is also what confuses me: all I have is the message space and the public exponents, I don't have the modulus. This leads me to think that I'm missing something.

Comment: @S.L. The message space is $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, so if you know the message space, you know $n$.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The RSA system in the question uses

1. a common modulus $n$ shared by multiple public exponents $e$
2. message space $[0,n)$
3. a 1024-bit mosulus $n$ with > 6 prime factors

This leads to security issues:

- Given a private exponent $d$, matching $e$, and $n$, it is possible to factor $n$ (see answers to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/16036/555)). Then, because of 1, it is trivial to find the private exponents for all other $e$, and decipher all cryptograms. This is a disaster if any of the various $d$ falls in the hand of an adversary (including if the various $d$ are held by persons with diverging interests).
- Message space $[0,n)$ of 2 strongly suggests textbook RSA, where encryption of $m$ in the message space is as $c\gets m^e\bmod n$. This is unsafe, in particular because a guess of $m$ can be trivially verified from $c$, $n$, and $e$, which all are assumed available to attackers. That's a disasters for a coin throw, the name of person on the class roll, a credit card number... Proper RSA encryption use random encryption padding, e.g. as in [RSAES-OAEP of PKCS#1v2.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=16), with typically a reduced message space.
- If 1 is combined with textbook RSA, and the same message is sent encrypted under multiple $e$, it can be deciphered without knowing any $d$ or the factorization of $n$ (see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16285/555)).
- The 1024-bit key size of 3, although seriously obsolete, would remain extremely hard to attack with 2 or 3 factors of about equal size. But with at least 7 factors, one must be 147-bit or less, and [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) can pull it out with little effort.