# Are the Common modulus attack, Common Factor Attack, and Wiener's attack different?

Tags: rsa, attack

Is there a difference between:

- Common modulus attack
- Common Factor attack
- Wiener's attack

or are these just a different name for the same attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Wiener's attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack);

  In Wiener's attack, an attacker may efficiently find $d$ when $d < (1/3) N^{1/4}$
- [Coppersmith's attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack)

  The Wiener attack works on low $d$, but Coppersmith attack works on small $e$. In general case, the Håstad's broadcast attack uses The Coppersmith method. In the simplest form, it uses CRT when the sender sent the same messages to different parties.
- [Common modulus attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack)

  In Common modulus attack, the modulus is the same but the public exponents are different.

As a result, they are different attacks with different names.

And, here a nice paper from Dan Boneh; [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf)