# Need help to understand this RSA common modulus attack Python code

Tags: rsa

I am reading [Practical Cryptography in Python](https://github.com/Apress/practical-cryptography-in-python). I have problem understanding the [common_modulus_decrypt()](https://github.com/Apress/practical-cryptography-in-python/blob/master/src/rsa_common_modulus.py) function. I think the prerequisite of RSA Common Modulus Attack is that two public exponents have to be co-prime, meaning $gcd(e_1,e_2)=1$, right? That is what I get from [how to use common modulus attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack)

If this is true, why does it do the following:

```
def common_modulus_decrypt(c1, c2, key1, key2):
    key1_numbers = key1.public_numbers()
    key2_numbers = key2.public_numbers()
    
    if key1_numbers.n != key2_numbers.n:
        raise ValueError("Common modulus attack requires a common modulus")
    n = key1_numbers.n
    
    if key1_numbers.e == key2_numbers.e:
        raise ValueError("Common modulus attack requires different public exponents")
    
    e1, e2 = key1_numbers.e, key2_numbers.e
    num1, num2 = min(e1, e2), max(e1, e2)
    while num2 != 0:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 % num2
    gcd = num1
    
    a = gmpy2.invert(key1_numbers.e, key2_numbers.e)
    b = float(gcd - (a*e1))/float(e2)

    i = gmpy2.invert(c2, n)
    mx = pow(c1, a, n)
    my = pow(i, int(-b), n)
    return mx * my % n
```

If gcd is always 1, why bothering with the while loop above? Also, I thought it should use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to get `a` and `b`. Why is it doing invert with `e1` and `e2`? Why is it using float()?

The last 3 steps for `i,mx,my` I can understand, as it assumes `b` is a minus value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use common modulus attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16283/how-to-use-common-modulus-attack)

Comment: No, it does not. As I mentioned, I assume co-prime is a required condition. Why doe does this code try to find gcd, as it should always be 1.

Comment: To use the Bezout identity and your question is not clear, too. What is num1 num2!

Comment: I added the missing part of this function, now it is complete. num1 and num2 are just the exponents of input keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step of the code;

1. $gcd = \gcd(e_1,e_2)$
2. $a = e_1^{-1} \bmod e_2$
3. $b =gcd - (a\cdot e_1))/e_2 \implies gcd = b \cdot e_2 + a\cdot e_1$; The [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)
4. $i = c_2^{-1} \bmod n$
5. $mx = c_1^a \bmod n$
6. $my = i^{-b} \bmod n$
7. $\text{return } (mx \cdot my) \bmod n$

Now check
\begin{align}
 mx \cdot my &=c_1^a \cdot i^{-b} \pmod n\\
  & = c_1^a \cdot (c_2^{-1})^{-b} \pmod n\\ 
  & =(m^{e_1})^a \cdot (m^{e_2})^{b} \pmod n\\
  & =(m^{e_1 a+ e_2 b}) \pmod n\\
  & = (m^{gcd})  & & \big[ = m \!\!\!\pmod n \,\textbf{ if } gcd=1\big]\\
\end{align}

The above calculation works for any $gcd$. This doesn't mean that we can resolve the message $m$ if $gcd>1$. What if $gcd \neq 1$ then for case 2, it is so-called Rabin Cryptosystem, security is shown to be equal to factoring. if $gcd =3$ is the cube-root attack possible and if the textbook RSA is used and the message $m < \sqrt[3]{n}$ recovery possible, and so on.

The conclusion is that they forget to write

```
  if gcd != 1:
      return -1
```

Writing good software is hard, writing good cryptographic software is much harder.

or [someone is wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/)

---

**The common modulus attack** is performed on Text-Book RSA when Alice and Bob use the same modulus $n$ with different public modulus. The first observation is that this is dangerous since Alice can learn Bob's private key, v.s. On the other hand, the eavesdropper ( passive attacker) knows the public keys $(n,e_1)$ and $(n,e_2)$ and when observed that the same message is sent to Alice and Bob (possibly broadcasting). Then the eavesdropper can resolve the broadcasted message $m$ if $\gcd(e_1,e_2)=1$. If they are using the same public exponent, this attack doesn't work.

When proper padding is used like PKCS#1 v1.5 and OAEP then this attack is not possible since they use randomization that prevents the equality of the same messages.

Comment: Thanks！This is the perfect answer. I think we should send this feedback to the book author to fix this.

Comment: That is why GitHub is there.