# How many p and q pairs are there in a 1024 bit modulus?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

I was reading: 
[Is sharing the modulus for multiple RSA key pairs secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/is-sharing-the-modulus-for-multiple-rsa-key-pairs-secure).

My question is: Given a 1024 bit modulus, how many pairs of 512 bit p's  and q's are there that would be able to be combined to create a 1024 bit modulus for use in RSA?

Since a 1024 bit modulus has not been factored, I am guessing we don't know, but I wonder if there is an equation?

I thought it would only be one set honestly: one p and one q multiplied together to get n. (Mainly because they only show 1 set in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768)

Maybe I don't understand but the side question would be: Given a 1024-bit modulus, how many pairs of e and d could one come up with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Given a 1024 bit modulus, how many pairs of 512 bit p's and q's are there that would be able to be combined to create a 1024 bit modulus for use in RSA?

The fundamental property is that any integer is a product of a unique multiset of primes.  As such, given an integer $n$ that is a product of two primes, those are the only two primes that, multiplied together, produce that $n$.  So, the answer is 1 (if you ignore swapping which prime you call $p$ and which you call $q$).  The fact that factorization is difficult means that it's hard to produce $p$ and $q$ given $n$; however that doesn't change the fact that $p$ and $q$ are unique).

> Given a 1024-bit modulus, how many pairs of e and d could one come up with?

That is a harder question to answer; given that there is no natural bound on how large $e$ and $d$ can be (as you can find arbitrarily large values that work), one answer might be "infinite".

If we ask for the number of $e, d$ pairs where both are limited to $\textit{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$ (which may sound like an odd limit, but turns out to be reasonable), well, we first note that $e$ can be used as a public exponent iff it is relatively prime to $\textit{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$.  In addition, for any $e$ which can be used as a public exponent, there is a unique $d$ within the range that works as the decryption exponent (which is why that odd looking limit is a reasonable one), hence counting potential $e$ values is equivalent to counting $(e, d)$ pairs.  And, given that the number of values relatively prime to $\textit{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$ is $\phi(\textit{lcm}(p-1, q-1))$, well that's your answer (or one less, if you don't count the $e=d=1$ pair.

Comment: One can have a good approximation by the help of Prime Number Theorem. The function $\pi(x)$ is approximated by $\frac{x}{log(x)}$ gave the number of primes less then x. The number of prime pairs to compose 1024 moduli is then something like $2.(\pi(2^{512})-\pi(2^{511}))$.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI: yes, but the question was about the number of factorizations of one specific $n$, not the number of possible 1024 bit $n$

Comment: One additional remark: If you require that your crypto system is secure then you cannot share n and use different values d and e. In that case, if you know one d you can calculate any other d.

Comment: it then seems like we are saying a 1024 bit RSA certificate *can* have various different private key values - as compared to 'just one'.

Comment: @james626: yes, if $d$ is a valid decryption exponent, then so is $d + k \cdot \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$ for *any* integer $k$; this gives an infinite number of possible private keys...

Comment: Wow. Fascinating. Thanks poncho. It's kind of surprising because I hear of THE private key - suggesting only one.