# about rsa decryption with given n,e,2d+phi(n)

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have given n, e, c, and 2d+phi(n). any idea how to proceed to solve that RSA. for values click on this:- https://pastebin.com/mdeSdfzD

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? This question shows absolutely no effort.

Comment: I have tried the same thing which is given in below comment. ed = 1+k*phi(n). but there is another variable k, after which I am not able to understand what to do next.

Comment: he's cheating on easyctf. https://easyctf.com

Answer (score 2):

```
p = 179625470269984575211291664517722616039787182426068867084101295486932993749787129633737153741496747351573119936946306867775629661781307731728093871384501392452057213703678422306940017327268991666011108647323837661852433288372793079254503318017584711837671484712835436166606958277493346384859583473813750793903

q = 165951900395573838473861177483977329257584913855055564650331190368208599646122670409920222286702764849767512840736219293650470102124983099032047151432801085844142882059163396523057801419384753318562498454796480286799673413582017708953121180295255267080043853111452400359241673145348291220080289048917975182701
```

*Hint:* $(2d + \phi(n))\cdot e \equiv 2 \pmod{\phi(n)} \implies (2d + \phi(n))\cdot e - 2$ is a multiple of $\phi(n)$

Comment: How you get p and q, Can you explain more, I am not able to understand it, it's important for me

Comment: See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6361

Comment: This doesn't make sense-- his `2d+phi(n)` multiplied by `e` in his example is a multi-hundred digit number. And `2 mod (number > 2)` always equals `2`.

Comment: @Arin: Above notation is for congruence.  It means $[(2d+\phi(n))\cdot e] \bmod \phi(N) = 2 \bmod \phi(N)$.

Comment: @Mark And as soon as you know a multiple of $\phi(N)$ you can factor $N$ using the approach as when you know the public and private key but not the primes.